# Server Side Timer for Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I will be developing a angular 4 application which will conduct some kind of exam. One of the requirement in the application is that there is time limit set for the exam. Once the exam starts the timer starts and by the time timer finishes the exam is to be submitted. I am looking for what all is possible way to get this done.

One way what I know is to get the java server on and run a thread with timer to for each exam. But Is it possible to get the job done in javascript keeping output same?

We can think it as a forever running server. If someone has something to share is most welcome.

Comment: What about: `settimeout(()=>YourApiCall(collectExamData()), examTimeInMilliseconds)`

Comment: If this is at all sensitive (for school students, for instance) then I would not rely on browser timers/time-- a bad actor with a bit of know-how could easily leverage the browser dev tools to bypass that.

Comment: Yes, client side timer is not suitable in my case. I want something server side. I can possibly  do it in java but need some insight about this aspect.

Comment: @HaiAlaluf what if browser tab is closed?

Comment: `java server` or `nodejs` ?

Comment: You right, you can't do it like that without any verification from server.

Comment: @JonasW. if you can explain me both then I would request for both.

Comment: Please decide for one. And add your considerations to your question. In its current state it is to broad..

Comment: Okay. Please explain about Node Js server